# An elementary differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gre-exam

I encountered this problem in last week's GRE subject test, and I could not solve it. So I venture to post it in here. The question is as follows:

$$y/t+te^{-t}=y'$$

asking me $$\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{y}{t}$$

*I am not sure if my memory is totally correct. If any others take the same exam and found I remembered the problem wrong, please point out in comments.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the ODE, you use the method of integrating factors. The proof is straight forward and can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). You write the left hand side of what SL2 rearranged as the derivative of a product
$$ y' - \dfrac{1}{t}y = te^{-t} $$

So to do this, compute (using the notation in the wiki article) $P(x) = e^{\int\frac{-1}{t}dt} = \dfrac{1}{t}$. Now what we can say is that

$$\dfrac{y'}{t} - \dfrac{y}{t^2} = e^{-t} $$

By construction however, we now can write the left hand side as the derivative of the product of two functions:

$$\left(\dfrac{y}{t}\right)' = e^{-t}$$

We can readily integrate both sides now, and we see

$$\dfrac{y}{t} = -e^{-t} + C, C\in\mathbb{R}$$

so that

$$y = Ct-te^{-t}$$

Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty} \dfrac{y}{t} = C-e^{-t} = \boxed{C}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a first order linear ODE:
$$y'-\frac1t y=te^{-t}$$

The solution to this has a nice closed form (see for example, [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_order_linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation)), so we can actually compute $y$, and then take the desired limit.

In particular, using the method on the liked page, we can compute $y=Ct-te^{-t}$, so $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac yt=\lim_{t\to\infty} C-e^{-t}=C$, so the limit will depend on the value of $C$ you take in the solution.  If the problem were in fact an IVP, then we could determine $C$, and we would get an actual number for the solution.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for this. I learnt this technique five years ago while I was in high school, and now it is completely forgotten. It is nice to see this again.